# Error upon updating entries in two tables(Parent/Child) MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two tables, **Parent** and **Child** with a one to many relationship. What I have done is, in the Create View(Parent) I have added a few of the Child fields in. So upon posting back to the controller, the Parent fields and Child Fields are posting at once. I receive them all correctly and manage to save to the Parent table, However I am having an issue saving to the Child table.

Table structure as follows:

```
Parent: ID,DateFrom,DateTo,Name,Version,Status;
Child: ID,ParentID, Item;
```

This is the Parent Controller - Create method:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,DateFrom,DateTo,Name,Version,Status")] Parent parent, Array childItems)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Parent.Add(parent);
                db.SaveChanges();


                var id = parent.ID;

                foreach (var _item in childItems)
                {
                    var items = new Child()
                    {
                        Item = _item.ToString(),
                        ParentID = id,
                    };
                    db.child.Add(items);
                }
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(parent);
        }
```

childItems is an array containing enteries to the Item field of the Child Table.

What I am trying to achieve is as the entry to the Parent table is made(which happens successfully), I would like to filter through the array and make an entry to the Child table along with the respective ParentID. But when I am running this, I am getting the following error.

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'

SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "FK_dbo.Child_dbo.Child_ParentID". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-ABC_Automation-20191120105424", table "dbo.Child", column 'ID'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I've debugged and noticed that in the foreach loop, The ParentID is holding its respective value, yet I cannot seem to figure out why the error is thrown.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Update:

Parent model:

```
public class Parent
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Child> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

Child Model:

```
public class Child
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ParentID { get; set; }
        public string Item { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ParentID")]
        public virtual Parent Items { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: post your `create table script`, seems like you have applied `foreign key` with same table `primary key`

Comment: Hi @Vishalmodi Please see the additions above, Thanks

Comment: @Prishen can you check if childItems in the action method isn't null? Will you include a screenshot of the array and its values?

Comment: hi @JerdineSabio Yes, I did check it out and it is returning values correctly

Comment: @Prishen, you have updated model but i want to see your **table script**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Child
{
[Key]
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Item { get; set; }
public int ParentID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Parent")]
public Parent Items { get; set; }
}
```

Try changing your Child class like this. The reason here is ParentID is our actual foreign key.

Comment: That would be an incorrect way of declaring a foreign key, this throws an error. The way it is declared above does not throw any errors in regards with the foreign key.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319366/EF-Code-First-Add-a-Foreign-Key-relationship

Comment: Can you please share the error which you are getting? Because the Name mentioned in the brackets after foreign key should be same as variable name.

Comment: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'ID' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection<T> where T is a valid entity type.'`

This is thrown when the compiler hits the Parent save portion in the Create Method.

Comment: Here you are using Parent Class as a navigation property and thus it you need to remove virtual keyword from your original code. For more details about navigation using foreign key you can check here https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: 100% correct, I have rectified this and everything seems to be working fine. Thank you @Bansari

Comment: Your welcome. I have edited the code just check if that's what is correct. So that the people coming here can get correct answer.